# JQGrid MVC Client side event not firing

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

**NOTE:** this is the JQGrid MVC component I am asking about which is created in C# server side.

I'm trying to get the ClientSideEvents to fire when a row is deleted.

```
ClientSideEvents = new ClientSideEvents()
{
AfterDeleteDialogRowDeleted = "doUpdates"
AfterAjaxRequest = "test", 
},
```

The only one that actually calls anything is AfterAjaxRequest which will call a test javascript function

```
function test() {
alert('test');
}

function doUpdates() {
alert('doUpdates');
}
```

any ideas, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @RezaRahmati I think it was just ordering of the JQGrid javascript file include.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I do not know if it is a bug. I solved the problem with a trick.

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#myGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
    }, 1000);
});
```

It was enough - all event handlers set with:

```
ClientSideEvents = new ClientSideEvents()
{
    AfterDeleteDialogRowDeleted = ....
    AfterAjaxRequest = ...., 
}
```

started to work